# What is Cargamantos?

Tags: significado, palabras-raras, nombres-propios

> Una relación exacta, con fechas y
>   detalles de que ella en persona había hecho cambiar las piedras de dos
>   generaciones de hermosas y dignas Cargamantos, y había vendido las legítimas a la
>   misma tienda. (García Márquez, Memoria de mis putas tristes)

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=cargamento) and some other sources say *cargamento* (not *cargamanto*) means cargo, ship, etc. However, I was unable to find any definition of *Cargamanto* or *Cargamantos* in any source. Is it a type of precious stone?

Grossman's translation of the novel uses the word as is so it has to be a proper noun. But, what exactly?

Comment: Without more context, it looks like a surname. She changed the jewels belonging to two generations of Cargamanto women (mother and daughters).

Comment: I agree with @angus, I understood it as a surname. In fact, searching a bit I see that there is a character in the book named _Florina de Dios Cargamantos_.

Comment: @DGaleano Por curiosidad, ¿existe el apellido Cargamantos en Colombia o es un chiste?

Comment: @Rodrigo No. Pienso que Gabo se lo inventó. En Colombia una de las clases de frijol más usado es el **cargamanto** (sin s al final) pero no conozco a nadie con ese apellido.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Googling for *Memoria de mis putas tristes* and *Cargamantos* [reveals](http://archivo.elnuevodiario.com.ni/opinion/182949-memoria-mis-putas-tristes/) what people are saying in the comments to your question: this is just the surname of a certain character in the book, called Doña Florina de Dios Cargamantos.

So when García Márquez says:

> ... había hecho cambiar las piedras de dos generaciones de hermosas y
>   dignas Cargamantos...

he's talking about the gemstones (jewelry) of two generations of lovely and dignified women in the Cargamantos clan.

Comment: @aparente thanks for the corrections in the text!!

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad you don't mind. // I have a vague idea the author chose "Cargamantos" because it's suggestive of some quality of the family.  Do you want to add something about that to your answer?

Comment: @aparente001 that's an interesting point I hadn't thought about. _Cargmantos_ is indeed a suggestive name, specially to convey the dignity of the women ([manto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OHpJo1w): _Vestidura, generalmente recamada, que cubre algunas imágenes de la Virgen desde la cabeza hasta la parte inferior de la peana_)

Comment: I'm picturing substantial, dignified women.  The sort who can wear heavy, impressive coats.  The opposite of the willowy type who tires easily.  But I don't know if that's what others would picture when reading this made-up last name.

Answer (score 0):

Probably refers to the cargamantos beans:

[image]

Comment: It is correct that **cargamanto** is a kind of bean but in the context of the question **Cargamantos** (with capital C) is a surname as described on the accepted answer by @fedorqui

Answer (score 0):

Frejoles, fríjoles, frijoles, porotos, caraotas, habichuelas in Spanish. English:  beans. Scientific name:  *Phaseolus vulgaris*.